# Baseline Grid with javascript

Tags: javascript

I try to write a simple script which alignment image containers to a css baselinegrid. 
Here is a nearly working example: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bigbigHase/jxrfqkxu/6/)

```
var lineHeight = 24;

$('.grid').height(function(i, h) { return Math.ceil(h / lineHeight) * lineHeight; });

$(window).resize(function() {
    $('img').each(function() {
        var heightDiv = $(this).outerHeight();
        $('.grid').css('height', Math.ceil(heightDiv / lineHeight) * lineHeight);
    });
});
$('img').load(function() { $(window).resize(); });
```

Only problem is that on resize all image containers take height of the last image instead of its own. can anyone help me please i'm very very new to javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want something closer to this:

```
$('img').each(function() {
    var heightDiv = $(this).outerHeight(),
        $parent = $(this).parent();
    $parent.css('height', Math.ceil(heightDiv / lineHeight) * lineHeight);
});
```

By referencing $('.grid'), you are calling all elements that contain a 'grid' class. What you really want is the direct parent.

Heres a working example of what I am talking about:
http://jsfiddle.net/jxrfqkxu/7/